# saving coordinates to a .gpx file and sending them to a site

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a tracking app that tracks a user through the use of gps. My plan is to save the coordinates and put them into a .gpx file so I can send them to a website so the tracks can be viewed by an administrator of the app. Is there a site that already exists that will accept my coordinates and plot the paths that it recieves?